# How to change the variable values using R programming in a data frame

Tags: r

I am learning R programming and have imported the CSV file. Now, I would like to change the variable value for symbol column. If the value is "ABCD.BO" then "Stock_T". If the value is "XYZ.BO" then "Stock_Y". I tried the below code but, I am getting a warning message and I checked the dataframe contains "NA" after changing.

```
df$symbol[df$symbol == "ABCD.BO"] <- "Stock_T"
df$symbol[df$symbol == "XYZ.BO"] <- "Stock_Y"

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$symbol == "ABCD.BO",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

symbol  Date    Adj.Close
ABCD.BO 9/21/2011   201.33
ABCD.BO 9/22/2011   192.9
ABCD.BO 9/23/2011   190.47
ABCD.BO 9/26/2011   185.95
ABCD.BO 9/27/2011   190.52
ABCD.BO 9/28/2011   191.82
ABCD.BO 9/29/2011   189.49
ABCD.BO 9/30/2011   186.74
XYZ.BO  2/10/2012   334.11
XYZ.BO  2/13/2012   336.14
XYZ.BO  2/14/2012   343.74
XYZ.BO  2/15/2012   351.83
XYZ.BO  2/16/2012   352.8
XYZ.BO  2/17/2012   350
XYZ.BO  2/20/2012   350
XYZ.BO  2/21/2012   354.63
XYZ.BO  2/22/2012   333.68
XYZ.BO  2/23/2012   340.57
XYZ.BO  2/24/2012   327.9
```

Answer (score 2):

here you go, try this:

```
df$symbol <- as.character(df$symbol)
df$symbol[df$symbol == "ABCD.BO"] <-"Stock_T"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Here are two.

The first is for changing all the factor levels. If you have a vector of symbols to change to, and they're in the same order of the `levels` of the symbols, it's probably easiest to do

```
within(df, levels(symbol) <- paste("Stock", c("T", "Y"), sep = "_"))
```

The second way is the "manual" way to do it, and can be used if you only want to change a couple of the factor levels.  In the code below, the line `symbol <- as.factor(symbol)` can be removed and the first column will be returned as character class. Leaving it in will factor the first column after the change.

```
within(df, {
    symbol <- as.character(symbol)
    symbol[symbol == "ABCD.BO"] <- "Stock_T"
    symbol[symbol == "XYZ.BO"] <- "Stock_Y"
    symbol <- as.factor(symbol) 
})
```

Note that you don't necessarily need `within` here.  I like it because it returns the changed data frame.

Comment: I would suggest being more explicit with `levels`, providing a named list, perhaps something like: `levels(df$symbol) <- list(Stock_T = "ABCD.BO", Styck_Y = "XYZ.BO")`

Answer (score 1):

It is not changing because the new value is not one of the named factors of that column. You can either use:

```
stringsAsFactors = FALSE in read.csv command
```

or convert symbol column to character:

```
df$symbol = as.character(df$column)
```

Then your commands will work.